# Get the JSON object that matches a specific value

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, filter

I'm building a little web-app to practice and learn Vue.js and working with APIs.

For a particular problem I want to solve, I would like to return the object that has the matching uuid that I request.

With my current knowledge, I understand I can do this by implementing some sorts and loops logic.

However I'm still new with JS, Vue.js, so I'm not sure if there is a better way to approach this.

Is there a built in function, or some form of "best practice" to approach this?

```
methods: {
    fetchItem(row) {
        // row.target_uuid  -- this is the UUID I want
        // this.$props.todoItems;   -- this contains the json objects
        // return this.$props.todoItems[i] where this.$props.todoItems[i]['uuid'] == row.target_uuid
},
```

This is a snippet of my $props.todoItems for context

```
[
  {
    "title": "Install Maris",
    "uuid": "9ec9ea6b-0efc-4f6a-be2e-143be5748d3a",
    "field_completed": "False"
  },
  {
    "title": "Figure out why VS Code sucks",
    "uuid": "85120da5-ee59-4947-a40f-648699365c73",
    "field_completed": "False"
  },
  {
    "title": "Start designing portfolio",
    "uuid": "243c1960-7ade-4a68-9a74-0ccc4afa3e36",
    "field_completed": "False"
  },
  {
    "title": "Meal Prep",
    "uuid": "85b64b18-9110-44d8-bd2d-8f818b0a810f",
    "field_completed": "False"
  },
  {
    "title": "Sharpen knives",
    "uuid": "8a7ac5f6-8180-4f20-b886-628fd3bcfc85",
    "field_completed": "False"
  },
  {
    "title": "Set up SSH keys",
    "uuid": "f879c441-8c05-4f24-9226-125c62576297",
    "field_completed": "False"
  }
]
```

Comment: 1) using javascript `filter` is right. 2) if appropriate, use `computed values` instead of `methods`. Computed values will be cached, therefore it's usually more performant than method

Comment: Thanks! Will look into filter and computed values!

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're looking for exactly one item (or the first item that matches) you should take a closer look at the `Array.find()` method provided by JS. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
Also take a look at all the other methods the Array prototype provides, most of them are fairly descriptive and solve most of the basic problems you'll encounter.

To use this in your Vue app you can either have a method that returns your todo based on a provided uid like this

```
todoByUid(uidToFind) {
  return this.todos.find(todo => todo.uid == uidToFind)
}
```

If you only care about a currently selected item a computed value as Jacob mentioned is the way to go:

```
computed() {
  selectedTodo() {
    return this.todos.find(todo => todo.uid == this.selectedUid)
  }
}
```